# How do browsers determine whether an URL in an href is relative or not when using a scheme?

Tags: html, http, url, browser, url-protocol

Suppose I have the following link tag: `<a href="tel:+15555555">Phone number</a>`.

How exactly does the browser know not to load the relative location `./tel:+15555555` from the current server and instead know that `tel` is supposed to be interpreted as a scheme?

Detecting host-relative URLs (`/…`) or protocol-relative URLs (`//…`) seems to be trivial. I guess HTTP-URLs (`http://…` or `https://…`) would be simple to special-case as well. But how does the browser go about parsing an URL with an arbitrary scheme? I know a valid scheme has to start with a lowercase letter and may only contain lowercase letters or the characters `+`, `-` and `.`, which limits the scope somewhat…
Of course I’m aware that the whole issue only pertains to scopes where relative URLs are valid (i.e. mostly the `href` and `src` attributes).

I’m looking for the links to some RFC (e.g. which forbids non-URL-encoded colons to be anything but scheme separators) as well as to the source code of various browser’s URL parsing internals.

Comment: @Pumbaa80: Colons are valid in any part of a URL. I’m looking for a spec that forbids them in relative URLs or when used unescaped: A Link to `special:Random` from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript could ambiguously link to both http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/special:Random as well as the `Random` URL of the `special:` scheme. I want to know WHERE EXACTLY this ambiguity is resolved (spec or source code).

Comment: It cannot be both absolute URI and relative path. Here is what [RFC3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-4.2) says: "A path segment that contains a colon character (e.g., "this:that")
   cannot be used as the first segment of a relative-path reference, as
   it would be mistaken for a scheme name.  Such a segment must be
   preceded by a dot-segment (e.g., "./this:that") to make a relative-
   path reference."

Comment: @Pumbaa80 could you add this comment as an answer and I will accept it (unless someone is willing to search through WebKit and Mozilla source codes, in which case they would deserve to get the accepted answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The href value is parsed as a URI (see RFC 3986). As a result of the parsing, the browser will know that this was an absolute URI, not a relative reference.

As a matter of fact, unescaped ":" is allowed in the path component; it's just that they need to occur after the first "/"; otherwise they could be parsed as scheme delimiter if the preceding characters are all valid scheme name characters.

See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3986.html#path

The RFC also has the following to say in [section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.2) (titled “Relative Reference”): “A path segment that **contains a colon character** (e.g., "this:that") cannot be used as the first segment of a relative-path reference, as it would be mistaken for a scheme name.  Such a segment must be preceded by a dot-segment (e.g., "./this:that") to make a relative-path reference.” (emphasis added).

Comment: So the relative reference is only tried if the parsing as absolute URI fails?

Comment: @Raphael Schweikert: Correct. There's a section in [the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#parsing-urls) that basically sets in stone what most if not all browsers already do.

Comment: Again, what's relevant is RFC 3986. That contains an ABNF (augmented Backus-Naur Form) that applies to all references, being absolute or not. The result of parsing will tell you whether it was absolute or not. See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc3986.html#rfc.section.4.1

Answer (score 0):

See [RFC 3966](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966) for the `tel` URI specification, and [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986) for the more generic URL specification. It's the colon (`:`) that separates scheme from the "hier part".

Comment: Thank you. But this does not really answer my question. I was looking for a much more generic answer: even if browser vendors special-cased `tel:` links (as they most likely do with `http(s):`, there are many other schemes which open in external applications, none of which are described in any RFC…